# Creating View using spatial queries in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, st-intersects, sql-view

I am trying to create a view from a selection. One layer contains indian states boundary as polygon and other world forest fire as points.

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT *
    FROM vnp14imgtdl_nrt_global_24h a, states b
      WHERE st_within(a.geom, b.geom)
      AND a.confidence = 'high'
      order by b.statename;
```

If I just run the select command it runs fine, but once I try to create a view it gives error stating

```
ERROR: column "gid" specified more than once
SQL state: 42701
```

Comment: Best practice is to use a `JOIN` instead of listing tables in the `FROM` and to ***always*** provide an explict list of each column in the `SELECT` clause, prefixed by the alias of the source table, with a column alias if the name is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use

SELECT a.* 
    FROM...

to show only forest fires points data AND geometries as results of the view.

Answer (score 6):

Seems clear enough, you have specified the column "gid" twice in your select statement.

I assume that both `vnp14imgtdl_nrt_global_24h` and `states` have a "gid" column and since you asked for `*` in the select this is a problem.

Simply, list out the actual columns your view needs and all will be well.